# php: preg_replace or DomDocument -> rebuild form?

Tags: php, preg-replace, domdocument

hey guys,
echo `$content` produces this

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="127.0.0.1">
    <p>
        something...
        <br/>
        something ...
    </p>
    <p>
        something else...
    </p>
</form>
```

Is it possible to either replace all

tags with something else e.g.  with a classname? Or is it possible to even remove all

tags and keep the stuff inside?

Id just love to apply my own formatting so I would need to strip off all `<p>` and `<br/>'s` However when removing `<p>`'s I need to keep it's content.

Any idea how to do this? Is that even possible? or should I use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all or a set of tags by providing the second parameter which lists the allowed tags.